# Calling a class and function in another file to edit the variable in the class

Tags: php, oop

```
class foo {

  public function bar(){

  $var = 10;

  return $var
  }

}
```

I have this class in one file, can i call this class and function in another file and somehow edit the variable $var, and then store it to the same variable so it can be used after in the class?

Comment: Yes you can call the method in another file, no you can't change the `$var` variable because you define it in the method. You should put it outside the method scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "reach into" functions and change variables used within them. From a sort of theoretical computer science standpoint, it doesn't even make sense. The variable `$var` only exists while the function is executing. When you call `$foo->bar()`, the code in it runs, creating the local variable `$var`, assigning `10` to it, then returning it. Then the whole scope is destroyed and the variable `$var` ceases to exist. It's not possible to alter it at all from code outside of `Foo::bar`, because it doesn't exist while code outside of `Foo::bar` is running. That's no to mention variable scope or encapsulation at all...

Most likely you'll want a property:

```
class Foo {

    public $var = 10;

    public function bar(){
        return $this->var;
    }

}
```

Public properties are a bad idea in and of themselves in most OO contexts, but that's a different cattle of fish I won't go into here.